# IBM.XMS .NET library: set up a flag

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq, xms

I am sending message to Websphere Message Queue, and I need to mark some messages with "Last Message" flag (it is default property for Message Queue). I am using IBM.XMS .NET library, but I haven't found ability to set up this property. Has anyone faced with that problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use `SetBooleanProperty` method to set "Last Message" flag, something like

```
message.SetBooleanProperty("LastMessage", true);
```

When receiving messages, check for the same property on the message to identify if it's the "Last Message" or not.

```
bool lastMessage = message.getBooleanProperty("LastMessage");
```